# How can I compare .NET SerialPort settings against API settings (apiBuildCommDCB)?

Tags: .net, api, serial-port, vb6

I need / want to update my VB6 serial comm port API to .NET SerialPort code.

I am still not getting it right.

In VB6, I am using this string to build the comm dcb via apiBuildCommDCB:

```
"57600,N,8,1"
```

This works fine.

In .NET, I have chosen these settings:

```
    _Port.BaudRate = 57600
    _Port.Parity = Parity.None
    _Port.DataBits = 8
    _Port.StopBits = StopBits.One
    _Port.Handshake = Handshake.None
    _Port.DtrEnable = True
    _Port.RtsEnable = True
```

It does not work, I am not receiving any data, so there must be something wrong.

Does anybody see what I am doing wrong or knows how I could compare the 2 versions against each other?

Thank you!

Comment: Typically, in VB6 you would also set the receive threshold to a non-zero value (usually 1). Can that be done in this model?

Comment: Please also provide the source code of the receiving process. Please refer to this help article. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)